# Access tabular data structure with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Using Javascript and D3js for the visualisation of data, I try to make use of a external csv file, which I downloaded from a data portal of the German government. -->
[Population of German Federal States by gender and date](https://www.govdata.de/suchen/-/details/destatis-service-12411-0021-test-test)
The data is available as csv and resembles the tabular structure of the also available xlsx file. There is a header and a footer, which I am not interested in (lines 1-5 & 28-32). 
The actual data have a hierarchy with the different states of Germany in the first row, followed by the gender in the second row, followed by the several rows with the number of the population at different dates (first column). At the end I would like to have an array of objects, such as

`[{name: "Bavaria", male:10000, female: 10000, overall: 20000},{name: ...}]`

So far I am using this code:

```
d3.csv("externaldata/12411-0021.csv", function(data){
    states = data;
});
```

This returns an array of objects, whereas every object seems to correlate with the lines in the document. My idea was to extract the information from these objects, but I dont know how to access/ parse the single rows.

Comment: You'll have to manually extract the data or transform it in a format `d3.csv` understands. If you go the first way then I recommend http://papaparse.com/ - used it before, good and stable performance.

Comment: For a small dataset like this, I think treating it manually might be an acceptable option. I thought about this too but I was not sure. Thx for your oppinion.

Answer (score 0):

If your column names are `name`, `male`, `female`, and `overall`, then the `states` var should contain exactly what you want it to based on your example.

So if the `states` var is an array of objects (or an array of associative arrays), you can access single rows like this:

```
var firstRow = states[0];
// > {name: "Bavaria", male:10000, female: 10000, overall: 20000}
```

And you can access the columns of that row like this:

```
var firstRowName = states[0]["name"];
// > "Bavaria"
```

or

```
firstRowName = states[0].name;
// > "Bavaria"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "bind" the data to the element within SVG. And once you've bound the top level element and data (i.e. csv to table) you also need to associate the lower level elements (e.g. objects and rows in your case).

You also need to decide how to structure your table behind the scenes. D3 puts all its elements within an SVG object, and SVG does not like tables. So you will probably want to add a group called table, groups called rows, and then rectangles and text for the cells.

So, first, you need to link the overall data object to the table. And then you need to tell d3 that each item within that data object corresponds to a row within your table.

```
var csv = d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return {key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })
    .get(function(error, rows) { console.log(rows); });
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

Your code should then look something like this (unchecked!):

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var table = svg.selectAll("g.table").data(csv).enter().append("g").attr("class","table");
var rows = table.selectAll("g.row").data(function(d){return d;}).enter().append("g").attr("class","row");
rows.selectAll("rect.cell").data(function(d){return d;}).enter().append("rect").attr("class","cell").attr("x","").attr("y","").attr("width","").attr("height","");
rows.selectAll("text.cell").data(function(d){return d;}).enter().append("text").attr("class","cell").attr("x","").attr("y","").attr("text-anchor","").text(function(d){ return d; });
```

Whether this particular code works will depend on your exact data structure.